# troubleshooting fonts in ggtext/markdown labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, ggtext

I'm trying to use `ggtext::geom_richtext()` to create bold/italic text (on Pop!OS [Ubuntu derivative] 22.04 with R-devel). I only get plain text (using PNG or PDF or using an on-screen X11/cairo device). The output all looks plain in every format. (I tried `ragg::agg_png"` too.) Any ideas for what to try next in the way of diagnosis/troubleshooting?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
grDevices::X11.options(type = "cairo")
theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 20))
test <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 2:4,
                   t = c("*a*", "**b**", "d"))
ggplot(test, aes(x,y)) + geom_richtext(aes(label= t), size  = 20)

ggsave("font_test.png")
ggsave("font_test.pdf")
system("eog font_test.png &")
system("evince font_test.pdf &")
```

[image]

---

```
─ Session info ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R Under development (unstable) (2022-05-16 r82365)
 os       Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu
 ui       X11
 language (EN)
 collate  en_CA.UTF-8
 ctype    en_CA.UTF-8
 tz       America/Toronto
 date     2022-05-20
 pandoc   2.9.2.1 @ /usr/bin/pandoc

─ Packages ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date (UTC) lib source
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 brio          1.1.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 cachem        1.0.6   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 callr         3.7.0   2021-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 cli           3.3.0   2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 colorspace    2.0-3   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 crayon        1.5.1   2022-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 DBI           1.1.2   2021-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 desc          1.4.1   2022-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 devtools      2.4.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 digest        0.6.29  2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 dplyr         1.0.9   2022-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 fansi         1.0.3   2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 farver        2.1.0   2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 generics      0.1.2   2022-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 ggplot2     * 3.3.6   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 ggtext      * 0.1.1   2020-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 gridtext      0.1.4   2020-12-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 labeling      0.4.2   2020-10-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 lifecycle     1.0.1   2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 markdown      1.1     2019-08-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 memoise       2.0.1   2021-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 pillar        1.7.0   2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 pkgbuild      1.3.1   2021-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 pkgload       1.2.4   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 processx      3.5.3   2022-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 ps            1.7.0   2022-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 purrr         0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 ragg          1.2.2   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 Rcpp          1.0.8.3 2022-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 remotes       2.4.2   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 rlang         1.0.2   2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 rprojroot     2.0.3   2022-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 scales        1.2.0   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 stringi       1.7.6   2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 systemfonts   1.0.4   2022-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 testthat      3.1.4   2022-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 textshaping   0.3.6   2021-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 tibble        3.1.7   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 tidyselect    1.1.2   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 usethis       2.1.5   2021-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 vctrs         0.4.1   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 xml2          1.3.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)

 [1] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
 [2] /usr/local/lib/R/library
```

Answer (score 1):

Should have looked at the [ggtext issues list](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext/issues/) first. This is [issue 83](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext/issues/83) there.

Installing the development version of `gridtext`:

```r
remotes::install_github("wilkelab/gridtext")
```

and restarting solves the problem.